# FFmpeg ignoring output pixel format

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` 4.2.2 on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine to clone the video stream of a USB webcam so that multiple applications can use the same feed. To achieve this, I simply clone to a `v4l2` loop back device:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

So far, this works reasonably well. I am able to successfully access `/dev/video1` which presents the same feed as `/dev/video0`.
Note: To make this work you need to ensure that the `v4l2loopback` device kernel module is enabled:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1
```

Next I'd like to convert the pixel format of the dummy device as the application that is accessing the dummy device can only handle `yuv422p` or `RGB` whereas my source device `/dev/video0` provides `yuv420p`. I thought that this would be a simple task that can easily be handled by presenting `ffmpeg` with an additional `-pix_fmt` argument on the output device like so:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 -pix_fmt yuv422p /dev/video1
```

While `ffmpeg` starts cloning the stream without any warnings or errors, it is still outputting in `yuv420p` instead:

```
joel@joel-ubuntu:~$ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f v4l2 -pix_fmt yuv422p /dev/video1
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x55ca407b9700] Time per frame unknown
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 6726.737520, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x480, 29.25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Output #0, video4linux2,v4l2, to '/dev/video1':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x480, q=2-31, 29.25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   76 fps= 34 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:02.52 bitrate=N/A speed=1.14x
```

No matter what `-pix_fmt` I pass, I always end up with `yuv420p` on the output.

I did several tests with both proper USB UVC webcams as well as DroidCam. The output pixel format never changes as expected. This is also not specific to requesting `yuv422p` as a pixel format. Also other formats are being ignored. Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Note: I have verified that `ffmpeg` is capable of the `yuv422p` pixel format (it is being listed when executing `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change pixel formats when using `-c:v copy`. Change to `-c:v rawvideo`.